# Find the slope of a normal line to a curve given curve equation and x coordinate

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry, implicit-differentiation

What are the steps to solving this problem? (Thank you in advance)

Find the slope of the normal line to the curve (x^2)-(xy)+(y^2) = 7 at the point where x=1. There are two possible answers - accept the SMALLER answer.

Where I started:

y' = (y-2x) / (2y-x)

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far.  The first step will be implicit differentiation, as you have included it in the tags I assume you know about this.

Comment: You’ve asked two questions in short order that both have to do with implicit differentiation. If you don’t understand how to attack these problems, I suggest that you review the course material that led to these exercises.

Comment: The normal line is the perpendicular to the tangent line (passing through the same point on the curve).  Do you know the relation between the gradients of two perpendicular lines?

Comment: Also your $y'$ seems to be wrong.  Hint: how did you differentiate the $xy$ term?

Comment: No, I do not know the relation between the gradients of two perpendicular lines.

Comment: -xy becomes -xy'-y

Comment: Google `gradients of perpendicular lines` and the first hit should give you what you need.

Comment: I got y' = (y-2x) / (2y-x)

Comment: Looks good to me.  Please edit your question with this correction.

Comment: What would be the next step after finding y' ?

Comment: The slope of normal at a point is $$-\frac{1}{y'}$$.

Comment: At a point on a curve, the tangent and normal will be perpendicular to each other and the product of the slopes of two perpendicular lines is $-1$. Let $m$ be the slope of the normal and $y'$ is the slope of the tangent. So, $$m\cdot y' = -1$$ $$m =-\frac{1}{y'}$$

Comment: With the equation you mentioned, I would plug in x=1 y=?

Comment: $y = 3,-2$ as you've found already. I've also written the answer below

Comment: James, I hope you won't mind if I say that your original question was pretty useless as it gave no real idea what you wanted.  When you added in your working, (i) it made it clear that you understand implicit differentiation, so no need to explain that; (ii) it made it clear that you had made an error in the differentiation, so you can be prompted to fix that; (iii) it made it clear that you also need to know about the normal and how to find its gradient.  This means you can get some help which addresses your needs.  So in future please ALWAYS show working with your questions.

Comment: Yes, in the future I will show that. Thank you for the review on my posted question, it is very helpful. I would also like to thank you very much for assisting me in understanding this tricky problem :)

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: Two lines with non-zero slopes are orthogonal iff the product of their slopes is $-1. $ And the normal line is orthogonal to the tangent line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Slope of the normal at a point $P =m= -\frac{dx}{dy}|_P = -\frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}\bigg|_P = -\frac{1}{y'|_P}$

As $x^2 - xy +  y^2 =7$, by differentiating w.r.t $x$,

$2x - xy' - y + 2yy' = 0$

> $y' = \frac{2x-y}{x-2y}$

and $$-\frac{1}{y'} = -\frac{x-2y}{2x-y}$$

At $x=1$, $1 -y+y^2 = 7 \implies y^2 -y -6 = 0\implies y = 3,-2$

At $(1,3)$ the slope is,

> $m_1 = -\frac{1}{y'} = -\frac{1-6}{2-3} = -5$

At $(1,-2)$,

> $m_2 = -\frac{1}{y'} = -\frac{1+4}{2+2} = -\frac{5}{4} $

Comment: IMHO using $\frac{dx}{dy}$ instead of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is likely to be very confusing for someone doing the topic for the first time.

Comment: Ok I'll edit that, Thank you!